# Play framework : tool to generate Evolutions scripts?

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Postgres database and I'm using play's evolutions.  I have 1.sql and 2.sql.  So far I've been writing the Ups and Downs by hand but there's certainly a better way of generating DDLs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no better tool than your hand :/

Auto-evolutions works well when working with ***1.sql*** on the beginning, but later you need to write'em yourself :/.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest [0xDBE](https://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/), which is yet another `SQL` client but somehow more clever than others. Whenever you perform drop/alter/create operations from user friendly interface, it displays performed `SQL` query in `SQL Preview`:

[image: Create new table with column]
[image: Drop table]

Comment: Nice tip, looks promising